# Can connect to wireless. No internet connection

Tags: wireless, internet, atheros

I'm connected to my wireless but I can't get any internet. 
ubuntu 12.10

Network Card: **Atherors AR928X** Adapter.

```
ifconfig wlan0 

    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet   HWAddr 70:1a:04:3e:26:06
              innet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10:0:0.255   Mask: 255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::721a:4ff:fe3e:2606/64   Scope:link
              UP BROADCAST RUNN MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
              RX packets: 5335 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:7885 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes (719.0 KB) TX bytes (695.5 KB)
```

A ping on `127.0.0.1` was the only ping that worked, not sure what that is though, my local ip address `10.0.0.1`.

I already tried rebooting the wireless. I just changed from Linux Mint to Ubuntu. Looking on my routers setting it showed my computer up as connected, but next time I looked it didn't.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `ip ad` and `ip r`.

Answer (score 0):

Does your **wireless internet** work on any other device (computer, phone)? If it does, it is probably a problem with your computer, which I  cannot help you with. However if your wireless internet doesn't work on any other devices, read on.

If you can connect to the network but not to the internet it is usually a problem with your router, modem or the cables running between. 
Firstly you should make sure that the internet cable going into your modem is in securely, then you should make sure that the internet cable going out of your modem and into the router is in securely on both sides. If you have done that and you can still not connect to the internet you should go to your router and unplug the internet cable going into it and plug it in directly into your computer's Ethernet port. If you can get internet then, your router is not setup properly or your router is in need of a replacement. If you still can't get internet you probably have a bad cable.

Good luck on debugging the internet. =)

Comment: Nope its just this computer